# Where should I instantiate the DUT object, in the testbench file or in the task?

Tags: verilog, testbench, verification

I am making a testbench in Verilog where it will call different test cases from different modules: each module, one test case/task.

Where should I instantiate the DUT object, in the testbench file or in the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DUT module should be instantiated in the testbench module file.  Modules can't be instantiated in a Verilog task.

See also:
[Can anyone help me to create a Verilog testbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073029/can-anyone-help-me-to-create-a-verilog-testbench)